What is Upload0.txt and why does it keep growing in size?
I recently discovered one of my company's virtual machines had started running out of storage space. After running WinDirStat I discovered that C:\Windows\appcompat\backupTest\Upload0.txt was taking 16 GB of space. Since I discovered this last week it has grown by a few GB. We have several other very similar vm's with the same setup, but their Upload0.txt is smaller than 1 GB and does not seem to noticeably grow in size. All of them are running Windows 10.
I have considered deleting it, but I don't want to delete it and break something. I would like to know what the file is used for and/or how to stop it from growing in size.
I have tried looking up what this file is for, but have not found any useful information on the internet. Restarting the machine did not change anything. The latest Windows updates has been installed, but it did not stop the .txt file from growing.
